# Statsmodels KernelReg standard errors

Tags: python, statistics, intervals, statsmodels, prediction

Is there a way to obtain prediction standard errors from `statsmodel.nonparametric.kernel_regression.KernelReg` function? I have seen on documentation that the `fit` attribute only returns point prediction and the derivatives, being the coefficients of the linear polynomial. I want to get the std err. of these coefficients to calculate the prediction std err.